# Distribution of daily log returns in Black-Scholes

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

We re in the Black-Scholes framework. So $(S_t)_{t \geq 0}, t \in \mathbb{N}$ (underlying) is a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ which evolute like a geometric brownian motion.

The SDE $dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$ has the well known solution (by applying Itos-formula) $S_t = S_0 \ exp \bigg \lbrace \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \bigg)t + \sigma W_t  \bigg \rbrace, \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{N}$.

So far so good :). But now when i just want to calculate the distribution of the daily log returns $Y_{t_i}:= log(S_{t_i} / S_{t_{i-1}})$:

$Y_{t_i} = log\bigg(\frac{S_{t_i}}{S_{t_{i-1}}}\bigg) 
= \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \bigg)t_i + \sigma W_{t_i} - \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \bigg)t_{i-1} - \sigma W_{t_{i-1}} 
= \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \bigg) + \sigma(W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}})$

i have a huge problem. Because obvoiusly they follow this distribution:

$Y \sim \mathcal{N}((\mu-\sigma^2/2),\sigma^2)$.

Why can you write $dS_t = (\mu +\sigma^2/2)S_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$ instead of $dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$ in the Black-Scholes formel ? What is the difference here ?

Comment: Could you provide references for those "several papers" or, if references are not freely accessible, direct quotations?

Comment: MCMC Methods for Continuous-Time
Financial Econometrics
Michael Johannes and Nicholas Polson ∗
January 25, 2006  P.41, Towards a Bayesian framework for option
pricing
Henryk Gzyl ∗
Enrique ter Horst †
Samuel W. Malone ‡
February 1, 2008 P.3

Comment: I found the Johannes and Polson paper.  Please read it carefully: its model for $dS_t$ differs from yours; where you use $\mu$, (if I am reading it correctly) they are using $\mu+\sigma^2/2$.  See p. 39, bottom.

Comment: so they setup lets say $\hat{\mu}:= \mu + \sigma^2/2$ ?